# Where is org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to make an Eclipse plug-in where the text in code-editor should get updated from a file. In most examples, I see people using IDE.openEditor(page, inputFile);
However, I cannot find the  org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE extension point. Downloading the jar and putting it in build path causes an error. I think it should be available in the list of possible extensions or dependencies. Any help on where to find it is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an extension point, it is a Java API that you call.

It is in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in so you need to add that to your plug-in's dependencies. You can do that in the MANIFEST.MF/plugin.xml editor on the 'Dependencies' tab in the 'Required Plug-ins' section. This will add the dependency to the `Require-Bundle` section in the MANIFEST.MF

Note: You should not need to download anything for Eclipse dependencies, the plugin should already be in your 'target platform'. It is also not correct to just put plug-in dependencies just on the build path - you must put them in the MANIFEST.MF